# Чтение из канала Golang

Tags: golang, context, golang-channels

Код работает. Но я не понимаю почему он работает в целом, если у меня есть два канала на чтение из **select**, но нигде нет ни одного канала на запись (или буфера откуда будет происходить чтение).

Я понимаю, что **time.After** и **Done()** возвращают значения типа **chan**, но разве у меня горутина не станет в очередь, ибо на запись ничего нет (и буфера также)?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const shortDuration = 500 * time.Millisecond

func main() {
    d := time.Now().Add(shortDuration)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), d)

    if cancel != nil {
        ctx.Err()
    }

    select {
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("overslept")
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println(ctx.Err())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что вы ожидали? `select` блокируется, пока один из каналов не станет активным.

Канал `time.After` должен активироваться через секунду, а канал `ctx.Done` через полсекунды (значение `shortDuration`). У вас происходит событие в канале `ctx.Done`, `select` срабатывает и программа завершается.

В каналы `ctx.Done` и `time.After` пишет системная горутина, которая отвечает за обработку событий таймера. Пока горутина `main` ждёт события в `select`, в системной горутине тикает таймер. Первым натикивает дедлайн контекста. Если вы зададите `shortDuration` длиннее одной секунды, то первым будет срабатывать таймер `ctx.After`

Кстати, зачем вы проверяете `cancel`? Эта функция для контекста с таймаутом никогда не `nil`, можно не волноваться.

Comment: Я все прекрасно понимаю, что Вы написали. Но ответа на вопрос я, увы, так и не получил.
Если еще проще, меня смущают стрелочки на чтение "<-". Почему в программе есть чтение, но нету записи (или буфера откуда будет производится чтение).

Comment: @YehorTverytinov Записи нет, так как в эти каналы пишет системная горутина таймера. Приложение может эти каналы только читать.

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Очень помогли)